# How to create a pop-up uitableview similar to instapaper's folder or settings?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, popup

Link to what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ViI.jpg

What I'd like to get is the same transparent border, up pointing arrow and tint for my own pop-up views.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [UIPopOverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Setting the contentViewController to your TableViewController. To attach it to a button you can use the `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` method.